# How does one remove only 3 instances of the same digits in an Array when there are more than 3 in the Array?

Tags: ruby, select, sequence, digits

Let's say I have an Array that contains more than three repetitions of a given digit.
I want to remove only three of those repetitions, and leave any remaining instances of the digit in the resulting array.

For example:

```
a = [2, 2, 2, 1, 6]
b = a.map{|i|
    num = a.select{|v| v == i}.size
    num == 3 ? "" : i
    }.reject{|v|
        v == ""
    }
```

gives me my desired result:

```
b == [1, 6]
```

However, in the below example, I want the last "2" to remain in the array.

```
# I want to reject ONLY triplets.
# In the below example, the last "2" should remain
a = [2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
b = a.map{|i|
    num = a.select{|v| v == i}.size
    num == 3 ? "" : i
    }.reject{|v|
        v == ""
    }
```

The result here is:

```
b == [2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
b == [1, 2]
```

I also have another code block, similar to the one above, using a bit different logic, but ends up with the same result:

```
a = [2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
newdice = a.reject { |v|
    if a.count(v) == 3
        x = v
    end
    v == x
    }
```

I'm at a loss, other than some nasty trickery that involves finding the index of the first instance of the 3x repeated digit, and slicing out [index, 2] from it.  There's got to be a more "ruby-like" way.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to delete the first three occurances of 2, ot the first occurance of three consecutive 2's?

Comment: Which position will be the target of deletion? Always the first three instance of the same digit? Is an element always a single digit?

Comment: @steenslag:  The first three occurrences of 2.  In the case of `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`, I'd like it to return `[2, 2]`.  Could also be `[2, 1, 2, 3, 2]`.

Comment: @sawa:  Yes, the element is always a single digit. The position doesn't matter.  Always the first three instances of the same digit.

Comment: See my last comment below for my admittedly clunky, but working, one-line solution.  Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would remove the first 3 elements that are = 2

```
3.times{a.index(2)? a.delete_at(a.index(2)) : nil }
```

if you want to remove the first 3 of any digits in the array then something like:

```
(0..9).each{|n| 3.times{a.index(n)? a.delete_at(a.index(n)) : nil }}
```

Matt's version further modified using the `if`-modifier:

```
(0..9).each{|n| {3.times{a.delete_at(a.index(n))} if a.count(n) >= 3}
```

Comment: Actually, on 2nd thought, I realize this works for anything *UP TO 3* instances.  I want to delete *exactly* 3 instances.  Not 2, not 4.  Thanks though!  I'm going to keep working on this.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I came up with this, using your solution:


`a = [2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
a.each{|v|
        a.count(v) >= 3 ? 3.times{a.index(v)? a.delete_at(a.index(v)) : nil } : nil
}`

Comment: I added some version of Matt's answer.

Comment: sawa:  I didn't realize that the `if` condition could modify the conditionality of the code ahead of it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want item to be displayed but below are the easy options if you want use

```
a = [2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
a.last(2) => [1,2]
a.uniq => [1,2]
```